# MySQL foreign key dependency resolution

Tags: mysql, database, dependencies, foreign-keys, rdbms

I am modelling a relational database where the following schema is used to describe 2 tables: [ERD Model](http://postimage.org/image/ifv7x8lrb/).

The rules specified are that:

1. An office has a manager
2. Each staff member is assigned to an office

In order to model this I created an ERD using MySQL workbench, which provided the following [DDL](http://pastebin.com/5wEGXKPH).

The issue I have is that in order to enforce that an office **must** have a manager, the foreign key in the office table is not nullable. Likewise, the foreign key in the staff table representing the office they work for is required for every staff and therefore **not** nullable. This makes sense to me in the model, however for the implementation it makes it impossible to insert data as each rely on the existance of tuples in the tables.

The only answer I can think of is to make the keys nullable such that one can temporarily exist without the other.

Is this the correct way to resolve the issue? The database will eventually be normalised to 3NF perhaps BCNF.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're attempting to record the relationship between offices and staff twice. Once in the office record and again in the staff record. You should only record the relationship in one place. Often this is done in a cross-reference table with two columns: Office_ID and Staff_ID. But it's also common to skip the third table and just record the relationship in one of the tables.

In this case, you can eliminate your problem by removing the Office field and foreign key from the Staff table. You'll be able to create as many Staff records as you need. Then when you create an Office record, you will be able to assign one of the Staff to the Office.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did consider this. So if I make an intermediatte table with a composite primary key (Staff_ID + Office_Id), how would I assign just one manager to an office. Could I keep the Manager foreign key in the office table, but have it reference a row in the cross-reference table? Thanks again

Comment: If you use an intermediate table, you would remove the Manager field from Office and add foreign keys on the intermediate table to both Staff and Office. If you use a composite primary key in the intermediate table then you'll be able to insert multiple managers per office. You could just use Office_Id as the lone primary key so that each Office only has one record in the intermediate table. Although, if you're doing that, then you really don't need the intermediate table at all and can just use the Manager field in the Office table since Offices to Managers is 1:1.